# call another controller using form widget in yii

Tags: php, forms, yii, action

I'm still grasping Yii framework at the moment and I'm trying to submit a form to go to a specific controller in Yii. What I did was I used a CMSActive Form widget(correct me if I'm wrong)

and the code that I placed:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CMSActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'file-form',
        'action' => '../controllers/FolderController/actionCreate',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>
```

I'm trying to call the actionCreate function which is from another controller, so I'm trying to call it but the error 404 that says:

> Unable to resolve the request
>   "files/controllers/FolderController/actionCreate".
>
> C:\xampp1.8\htdocs\yii_1.1.13\framework\web\CWebApplication.php
>
> line # 286
>
> 0
>   C:\xampp1.8\htdocs\yii_1.1.13\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(141):
>   CWebApplication->runController('files/controllers/FolderController') 1
>   C:\xampp1.8\htdocs\yii_1.1.13\framework\base\CApplication.php(169):
>   CWebApplication->processRequest() 2
>   C:\xampp1.8\htdocs\cubecms\backend\www\index.php(12):
>   CApplication->run() 3 {main}

I'm thinking that it could not see the function since it's an error 404, but am I calling it correctly?

My controller has an actionCreate function, and I'm good once I can get inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

`action` expects a [route](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#route) or a [valid url](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#action-detail) and not a path to the action.

```
`action`=>array('/controller/action',...)
```

Comment: how do I know the baseurl of the action so I would know where to start?

Comment: You should read through http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller to understand how controllers and actions relate to urls.

Answer (score 0):

Place

$this->**createUrl**('/controller/action');

All url must be made using createUrl or createAbsoluteUrl method.

Here it is in fact url and need not to be  /controller/action

If you want it to be submitted on /foo only then place '/foo' in createUrl